# How can I combine ARFoundation with Vuforia?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I wanted to know if anybody managed to use ARFoundation with Vuforia.

The reason we want to do this is that we find the Vuforia ground plane not flexible and we found out the ground plane is less accurate than the native capabilities but we still want to keep the image tracking (without the extended tracking because since 7.5 we really don't like the fact that targets are extended by default).

Comment: But Image tracking is also present in ARFoundation. So why not just use ARfoundation ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no programming question is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Vuforia and AR foundation in the same project , The answer is yes it is possible.
Only Thing we need to make sure is please disable the "Include AR core Library" settings under Vuforia configuration.